# How can I separate a large React codebase based on re-usable components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, npm

I currently have a large, universal react application. I want to extract some of the components out of the app and put them in a separate repo so other teams/project can import them and use them on their frontends.

Eg: Repository 1 that contains  component

Repository 2 is a web app that can import  from Repository 1

### Some concerns that I have:

**I want to limit the amount of duplicate / unused code**

Similar to how you can import a single lodash function (import forEach from 'node_modules/lodash/lib/...' vs import { forEach } from 'lodash',

I want components to be able to be imported standalone, without having to bundle all components

**I don't want to duplicate dependencies**

If all of my components are built as single files and they all require React, I'll have bundled React into my codebase as many times as the number of components that I have.

---

Is it a good idea to have a separate built file for every component that I export? If I don't import a built file, would I have to explicitly tell webpack in my main repository to look in my component's node_modules?

Comment: sounds like you could use a tool that helps with bundling multiple packages like knit https://github.com/knitjs/knit or lerna https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Comment: thanks, https://github.com/lerna/lerna looks interesting. From my understanding, it is essentially doing the same thing that NPM+3 and peerDependency tries to solve?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your React components are now in different subfolders of your project. Why don't you move them into separate Git repos and connect those repos back to your app using [Git SubModules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

You can also make React components npm packages and install them using NPM.

Every app that uses a component will need to include it into its build chain. I don't think a component should really build itself.

Comment: If I install each component as an individual NPM package, my main concern is making sure that each of those packages doesn't include react and other shared libs as a dependencies installed in their own node_module subdirectories. It looks like npm3+ and/or peerDependency declaration can prevent this

Comment: @Jon Yes, there is a deduplication mechanism for that. It was there in NPM2, but just wasn't turned on by default as I remember.